# Error in Django Channel during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

Tags: django, django-channels

I was following the [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4nwRQPXD8w&list=PLOLrQ9Pn6cazStWmb0DpaNgFz_RzKawo8&index=2) tutorial on youtube.

The browser gives an error "(index):21 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/asas/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
(anonymous) @ (index):21"

Code:

chatroom.html

```
<script>
    const roomName = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('room-name').textContent);

    const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'ws://' +
        window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' +
        roomName +
        '/'
    );

    chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log(data)
        document.querySelector("#user-hello").innerHTML = (data.tester)
    }
</script>
```

chat/routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatRoomConsumer),
]
```

chat/comsumers.py

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class ChatRoomConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )


        await self.accept()

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'tester_message',
                'tester': 'Hello World',
            }
        ) 
    async def tester_message(self, event):
        tester = event['tester']

        await self.send(text_data = json.dumps({
            'tester':tester
        }))


    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ASGI_APPLICATION = "core.routing.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add *.as_asgi()* after Consumer:

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatRoomConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```